# How to write all values into a file from a loop, not just the last value?

Tags: loops, file, perl, io

I would like to write all server values in text file. But my output text file can only write one last value. For example, `$theServer` values are

```
as1tp.com
as2tp.com
as3tp.com
as4tp.com
as5tp.com
```

Instead of writing all those server values in output text file, I can only write one last value `as5tp.com` in my text file. Below is my code. How do I write all values into `tier1.txt` file?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $outputfile= "tier1.txt"
my $theServer;      
foreach my $theServernameInfo (@theResult){   

    $theServer = $theServernameInfo->[0];   
    print "$theServer\n";
    open(my $fh, '>', $outputfile) or die "Could not open file '$outputfile' $!";
    print $fh "$theServer";
    close $fh;
    
}
```

Comment: Move the open and close outside of the loop

Comment: @ikegami i tried to move open and close statement outside of the loop also only see one  last rerver name :(

Comment: There is a semi-colon(`;`) missing in 3rd line.

Comment: Also could you please show us what is the `Dumper` values for `@theResult` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. As the commenters suggested, I inserted the missing semicolon. I moved `open` and `close` outside the `foreach` loop, so that the file is not overwritten at every loop iteration. Remember that you opened it in `'>'` mode (write, not append):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $outputfile = "tier1.txt";
open( my $fh, '>', $outputfile ) or die "Could not open file '$outputfile' $!";

foreach my $theServernameInfo ( @theResult ) {   
    my $theServer = $theServernameInfo->[0];    
    print "$theServer\n";
    print { $fh } "$theServer\n";   
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: @ikegami, vkk05 : Thank you for the comments. I used the ideas in your comments, added some explanations and made this into a community wiki answer.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't need to make it a community wiki :)